# Java: cannot find symbol when reference an object from other class

Tags: java

I am new to Java. I am writting a simple quiz program by following a tutorial from youtube [Building a Multiple Choice Quiz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCIjHTlztNg) . I created 2 class Question.java and App.java. After compiling those class on Terminal, it seems the object Question can't be reference

```
public static void takeTest(Question [] questions) {
                                ^
  symbol:   class Question
  location: class App
App.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        Question [] questions = {
        ^
  symbol:   class Question
  location: class App**
```

**This is my code:**
Question.java

```
public class Question {
    String prompt;
    String answer;

    Question(String prompt, String answer) {
        this.prompt = prompt;
        this.answer = answer;

    }
}
```

App.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        String q1 = "What color are apple?\n"
                + "(a)red/green\n(b)Orange\n(c)Magenta\n";

        String q2 = "What color are banana?\n"
                + "(a)red/green\n(b)Yellow\n(c)Blue\n";

        Question [] questions = {
                new Question(q1, "a"),
                new Question(q2, "b")
        };

        takeTest(questions);

    }

    public static void takeTest(Question [] questions) {
        int score = 0;
        Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(questions[i].prompt);
            String answer = keyboardInput.nextLine();

            if (answer.contentEquals(questions[i].answer)) {
                score ++;

            }

        }

        System.out.println("You got"+score+"/"+questions.length);

    }
}
```

I have tried to search how to fix this but can't find a solution, any help would be very greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is command you are running to compile the classes ?

Comment: Hm for me it compiles fine ....

Comment: Are all classes in the same package? If not, you need to import Question in App. Maybe you should publish your code in Github so one can have a closer look.

Comment: @MarkSchäfer no, everything needed to solve the problem should be inside the question.

Comment: You may need to import the Question object. If your package is a.b, then import a.b.Question;

Comment: Update: those files are successfully compiled when I delete the package: `package finalprogram` <br>
Thank you guys

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I don't agree, sure this is a small problem, but there are also large code examples which does not fit easily into a question. An external repository which contains a complete project and which can be cloned and inspected seems to be much more efficient.

Comment: @MarkSchäfer that's the reason we usually ask for [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If the question requires your whole codebase it's too broad. See the section "Help others reproduce the problem" in [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Put App.java and Question.java under same directory,cd that directory and run following commands:

```
javac App.java

java App
```

Comment: I put those file under same directory, also cd that directory and run those file by Mac Termminal but it doesn't work.
My package is finalprogram, I tried to import the Question by `import finalprogram.Question;` but  it doesn't work. My Mac has been install Java JDK 1.8, something go wrong with my Mac?

Comment: Update: those files are successfully compiled when I delete the package: `package finalprogram`.
Thank you guys